# Batch generated file produces encoding error with latex

Tags: unicode

**The goal:**
This is for an exam. I have a program which should be compiled and executed by batch script. Another batch script calls that first batch an writes the output to a `.txt` file. Then the contents of that `.txt` file should be included in a document which is produced with Latex.

**The problem:**
Latex produces an character encoding error during the build. Error message:

> Package `inputenc` Error: Keyboard character used is undefined in inputencoding 'utf8'

The generated file looks like this:

```
Ausgabe generiert am 11.05.2013 um  8:28:11,39
************** Skript zur Kompilierung der Source-Dateien **********************
Kompilieren der Sourcedateien zu "Program.exe"

Microsoft (R) Visual C# 2008 Compiler Version 3.5.30729.6400
, für Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Version 3.5
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

Erfolgreiche Kompiliereung
```

In line 6 the german umlaut 'ü' (ue) is the problem. Also there is a problem with the # character later.

LaTeX config:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

Code is included like this:

```
\lstinputlisting[style=tests]{log/log.txt}
```

The strange thing, I have special characters like Umlaut (äöü) etc. all over the place in my document and that works fine. If I copy a file from my project and rename it to `log.txt` it works fine. But if I create a new file on the file system (or generate it with the script) and write some special characters to it, it crashes.

**More details:**
I am using Windows 8, Texnicenter and MikTex. The listing style looks like this:

```
\lstdefinestyle{tests}{
    language=,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,       
    numbers=none, 
    breaklines=true,             
    frame=none,                     
    breakatwhitespace=false,            
    backgroundcolor=\color{hellgelb},  
    literate=
    {Ö}{{\"O}}1
    {Ä}{{\"A}}1
    {Ü}{{\"U}}1
    {ß}{{\ss}}2
    {ü}{{\"u}}1
    {ä}{{\"a}}1
    {ö}{{\"o}}1
}
```

**What I have tried:** Googled my a.. off. I tried to use all possible codepages in the batch file like: 1250, 1252, 850, 65000, 65001, 1200, 1201, 12000, 12001. Nothing works.

I'd appreciate your help very much!

**Edit**
Batch that writes the output:

```
@echo off
SET log=%~dp0\latex_doku\log\log.txt
SET skripts=%~dp0..\..\cd\batch
SET folder=%~dp0\latex_doku\log    SET result=%~dp0..\..\cd\unit_tests\results\TestResult.xml

ECHO Generieren der Ausgabedatei...
ECHO Ausgabe generiert am %DATE% um %time%>%log%

REM kompilieren
CALL %skripts%\compile.bat>>%log%

REM Systemtests ohne Eingabedateien ausfuehren
CALL %skripts%\run_tests.bat>>%log%

REM ausfuehren
CALL %skripts%\run.bat>>%log%

REM TestResults
IF NOT EXIST %result% GOTO EXT
xcopy "%result%" "%folder%" /y

:EXT
pause
```

When I dont specify a codepage the result looks like this:

[image]

When I specify cp 1252 for example it looks like this:

[image]

It is strange that the character is shown correctly in the editor...

Comment: Can you show the batch, that writes the output (here or at pastebin)?

Comment: Yes sure, I forgot to show it. I tried different codepages with chcp command.

Comment: Does this batch write the input for Latex? Or the other called batches?

Comment: It calls this one: http://goo.gl/gmwnk. so it creates the log.txt file which is the input for latex but the contents are produced partly by this batch, the compile batch, the program.exe and the other batches...

Comment: I have no clue. I would recommend, if you get no answer here, ask in a forum where the guys are more familiar with those special character issues (eg. [chip.de](http://forum.chip.de/batch-shell-skripte-191/) or [administrator.de](http://www.administrator.de/category/1101995812).

Comment: You somehow have to make sure that your log file is encoded in UTF-8, too. I have no idea how to do this on Windows, though.

Comment: The codepage on windows for UTF-8 is 65001. This can be specified within the batch file with the command chcp. Anyhow this doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Do you know package [`listingsutf8`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listingsutf8)?

It allows you to print a source in UTF8 (changed to Latin1) with the code:

```
% in preamble:
\usepackage{listingsutf8}[2011/11/10]

% to print the utf8 code:
\lstinputlisting[%
  style=tests,%
  inputencoding=utf8/latin1,%
]{log/log.txt}
```

Because you gave no MWE I can't test if it is working for you. Please do it by your own.